# A general way to prove this statement

Tags: matrices

My math textbook states that "If we are given two symmetric matrices A and B, AB+BA will also be symmetric and AB-BA will be skew symmetric". I can prove this statement for a 2 by 2 matrix in the following way.
[image][image]

But how can I prove this statement for a general matrix of order n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition:

$A$ symmetric $\iff A = A^T$

We also have the following properties:

$[A+B]^T = A^T + B^T$

$[AB]^T = B^T A^T$

So, given that $A,B$ are symmetric, we know:

$[AB + BA]^T = [AB]^T+[BA]^T = B^TA^T + A^TB^T = BA + AB = AB + BA$

Hence, $AB + BA$ is symmetric.

Also, $[AB-BA]^T = [AB]^T - [BA]^T = B^TA^T -A^TB^T = BA - AB = -(AB -BA)$

Hence, $AB-BA$ is skew symmetric.

If you want a proof for the properties I used, let me know. Also, questions are welcome. Don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 1):

$$(AB)^{T}=B^{T}A^{T}\\(A\pm B)^{T}=A^{T} \pm B^{T}$$ so apply those properties to $$AB+BA \to (AB+BA)^{T}=(AB)^{T}+(BA)^{T}\\=B^{T}A^{T}+A^{T}B^{T}=BA+AB$$

AND DO THIS AGAIN TO $$AB-BA\\(AB-BA)^{T}=\\(AB)^{T}-(BA)^{T}=\\B^{T}A^{T}-A^{T}B^{T}=\\BA-AB=\\-(AB-BA)\\SKEW- SYMMETRIC$$